# dataWithContentsOfURL returns nil for smb URL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, smb

I have a file path like so:

```
smb://servername/Folder/Folder/FTP/ANC/ANC.pdf
```

and I am trying to read this file:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"smb:///servername/Folder/Folder/FTP/ANC/ANC.pdf"];

NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

but `urlData` is returning `nil`. Why? The path is 100% correct.

Comment: "smb://servername/folder/folder/ANC/ANC.pdf" != "smb:///servername/Folder/Folder/`FTP`/ANC/ANC.pdf"

Comment: thats was just an example. The example is now fixed.

Comment: As mentioned in the other post, if the scheme is included in the URL string you have to use `[NSURL URLWithString:@"smb:///…"`